# How to capture dropped events in PySpark structural streaming job

Tags: pyspark, databricks, spark-streaming, delta-live-tables

I have a PySpark streaming job which drops duplicate events by a session id. I have a watermarking window of 30 min.
Snippet:

```
unique_df = df.withColumn("timestamp", current_timestamp()).dropDuplicates(session_id).withWatermarking("timestamp", 30)
```

I have two asks. First, I want to capture all the dropped events due to the above code. I tried using exceptAll and joins but did not work due to the Streaming job nature.

```
dropped_df = df.except(unique_df)
```

And

```
dropped_events = df.join(unique_df, on=session_id, how="left_anti")
```

Second, let's assume a session_id=abc123 comes at 9:00 and due to some glitch, we see session_id=abc123 at 11:00. Since it is out of the watermarking window, I want to mark this duplicate and capture it separately like above.

Can someone advise how can I achieve this in a streaming env?

Comment: How about creating a window function, with a row_number on session_id as partition? That way at the end you can filter by row_number, where row_number > 1 would be your dups and and row_number == 1 would be the ones to keep